# bootstrap tab causing jQuery events to disappear?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

This may be a vague question. I have a page with 3 tabs using bootstrap's tabs. Within the tab's contents there are click events. Some jQuery, some using knockout's click binding, and one using onclick. When I first go to any tab everything works fine. When I leave that tab to go to another tab and then return, none of the click events work anymore except the one made with onclick. At first I thought it was knockout causing something to go haywire, but I commented out the knockout code and it still happens. The events are pretty basic:

```
$('#prodSalesTable').on('click', 'td.control', function (e) {
    ....
}
```

Here's the tab init code. Again, basic.

```
$('#productDetailTabs a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Tab code:

```
<ul id="productDetailTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#informationTab" data-toggle="tab">
        INFORMATION</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#vocTab" data-toggle="tab">
        VOC</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#htsCountrySpecTab" data-toggle="tab">
        TARIFF CODE</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
        <section id="informationTab" class="tab-pane active">....</section>
        <section id="vocTab" class="tab-pane">....</section>
        <section id="htsCountrySpecTab" class="tab-pane">....</section>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this fixed it, but on the tab links I changed data-target to href and it now no longer seems to delete the click events.